# Getting name of geometry column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, fields-attributes

Depending on the table I'm working on, the geometry column does not always have the same name, for example in my data it is called sometimes `"the_geom"`, `"geometry"`, `"geom"`, or even `"geometrie"`. How can I get the name of this attribute in QGIS?

Comment: What does your geometry column contain what you can't access via `$geometry`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open DatabaseManager, you can navigate to 'virtual layers'.  Select your layer and look in the tab 'info'.

[image]

Here you get a list of all your fields, the geometry-field included.

Comment: Thanks, however there is a problem, I tried with a random table. The field name is different in QGIS DB Manager ("geometry") and in PostgreSQL (" geometrie ", the real name). It looks like whatever the name of the geometry column, it is renamed by default "geometry" in DB Manager. Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: @Eliasse You can access your postgres-table via DBmanager.  Select the table and look in the info-tab.  There the name of your geometrycolumn will be shown as registered in PostGIS

Comment: Thanks it's working !

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I Had the same problem when defining a dynamic query for a virtual layer and stumbled over this discussion.

My solution was the understanding, that in QGIS queries/expressions the "geometry"/"$geometry"-pseudo-SQL-keyword allows the access to *any* vector-geometry-souce without knowing the name of that column, even if there is no physical column, think about shape-file-Layers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a programmatic solution: With PyQGIS you can get the name of the geometry column via the `QgsDataSourceUri` of the `QgsVectorDataProvider`, e.g. for the active Layer:

`iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().uri().geometryColumn()`

will give you:

[image]